# Is it on-topic to ask about the explanation of crossword clues

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic

Question as above.
I dont mean asking for the answer, but the **explanation of the answer**

Example - this clue.

```
Rush animal from behind
```

Answer: `Reed`

Eventually figured out both the meanings - but could I have asked here about this?

Comment: Ok, now you've got me curious: what is the explanation for your example? (Does *reed* have meanings I don't know about?)

Comment: @Martha: "Rush" and "reed" can both refer to grass-like plants, and "reed" backwards is "deer".

Comment: @Mitch Schwartz: thanks. That's painful, even for a crossword clue.

Comment: @Martha: yes i had to google for the "Rush reed" bit - was totally unaware of that meaning

Comment: @Martha: that depends what crossword tradition you’re used to.  In standard US crosswords (i.e. NYT-style), yes, it would be odd.  In *cryptic crosswords* (more popular in UK/Commonwealth; e.g. the Times or Guardian), that’s a pretty straightforward clue.

Comment: @JoseK: the blog [fifteensquared.net](http://fifteensquared.net) is an excellent source for cryptic crossword explanations — they give annotated solutions of several notable crosswords daily (the major UK newspapers, and several international ones, iirc).

Comment: @PLL: thanks for the link, i got a couple of cryptic links to check now

Comment: @Marthaª. I'm useless at cryptic crosswords, but thought this one was fairly easy. (Non-cryptic crosswords are pointless.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say it is on-topic, it is some kind of [single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests), with sometimes a hint of [etymology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology).